# Hilbert- Schmidt class is an ideal

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, c-star-algebras, compact-operators

Definitions:

> 1 - An operator $y\in B(H)$ is said to be of trace class if $y$ is compact, and also $\sum|\alpha_n| <\infty$ where $\alpha_n \in \sigma(y)$ and $y$ has a representation $\sum \alpha_n \xi_n\otimes \eta_n $ for orthonormal systems $\{\xi_n\} , \{\eta_n\}$.
>
> 2 - An operator $x\in B(H)$ is said to be of Hilbert-Schmidt class if $x^*x$ is trace class.

By above definitions I can not show that $yx \in L^2(H) $ (Hilbert-Schmdt class), where $y\in B(H)$, and $x\in L^2(H)$. Please give me a hint. Thanks.

Comment: I guess that somehow one has to use the fact that the trace class is an ideal.

Comment: @JankoBracic : but, how does one show it?

Comment: For the proof that the space of trace class operators is an ideal one needs to assume some knowledge about the trace on $B(H)$ (here it means $tr(x)=\infty$ if $x$ is not a trace class operator).

Comment: @JankoBracic : I need to show that $L^2(H)$ is an ideal by above definition not $L^1(H)$. I can show that $L^1(H)$ is an ideal, but mu problem is $L^2(H)$.

Comment: One needs the following property of the trace $tr(uv)=tr(vu)$ for $u, v\in B(H)$. With this, one has: if $x$ is arbitrary and $y$ is HS, then $tr((xy)^*(xy))=tr(y^*x^*xy)=tr(x^*xyy^*)<\infty$ since $yy^*$ is trace class.

Comment: @JankoBracic : yes, you are right. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming $H$ is a separable Hilbert space.  Let $(e_k)$ be an orthonormal basis of $H$ of eigenvectors of $x^*x$.  Then 
$$
\sum \langle (yx)^*(yx) e_k,e_k\rangle
=\sum \|yxe_k\|^2
\le \|y\|^2 \sum \|xe_k\|^2
=\|y\|^2_\infty \sum \langle x^*xe_k,e_k\rangle
<\infty
$$
because $x^*x$ is trace class and $y$ is bounded.  Since the left-hand side is independent of the choice of basis (see Problem 5.64 page 433 [here](https://books.google.ch/books?id=0ijlBwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=kubrusly+elements+of+operator+theory&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwie9PThoPvXAhUFtxoKHQuoDeYQ6AEILDAA#v=onepage&q=kubrusly%20elements%20of%20operator%20theory&f=false)), we can replace the basis $(e_k)$ by a basis of eigenvectors of $(yx)^*yx$, which shows that it is trace class.